# How to change the size and spacing of Plotly's sublopts?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python, subplot, plotly.graph-objects

How is it possible to manipulate the **spacing between rows**(e.g. increasing the space between fist two rows and final two rows) and the **size of charts inside the figure** (e.g. making pie chart bigger)?

In my example, I'm trying to visualize multiple data columns from [Telco Customer Churn dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/blastchar/telco-customer-churn/data) ([download 176kB](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/blastchar/telco-customer-churn/download?datasetVersionNumber=1)) using plotly's `FigureWidget` and `make_subplots`.
[image]

This code loops through 8 columns, adds 1 pie chart and one bar chart for each column.

```py
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

# Read data
df = pd.read_csv("./WA_Fn-UseC_-Telco-Customer-Churn.csv")
df['SeniorCitizen'] = df['SeniorCitizen'].map({0: 'No', 1: 'Yes'})

# Define subplot titles and data columns
data_cols = ['PhoneService' ,'MultipleLines' ,'InternetService' ,'OnlineBackup' ,'DeviceProtection' ,'TechSupport' ,'StreamingTV' ,'StreamingMovies']
titles = ['Phone Service' ,'Multiple Lines' ,'Internet Service' ,'Online Backup' ,'Device Protection' ,'Tech Support' ,'Streaming TV' ,'Streaming Movies']

fig = go.FigureWidget(make_subplots(rows=4, cols=4, specs=[
                                                        [{'type':'domain'}, {'type':'domain'}, {'type':'domain'}, {'type':'domain'}],
                                                        [{'type':'xy'}, {'type':'xy'}, {'type':'xy'}, {'type':'xy'}],
                                                        [{'type':'domain'}, {'type':'domain'}, {'type':'domain'}, {'type':'domain'}],
                                                        [{'type':'xy'}, {'type':'xy'}, {'type':'xy'}, {'type':'xy'}]]))

row, col = 1, 0
for i, (title, data_col) in enumerate(zip(titles, data_cols)):
    row, col = divmod(i, 4)
    row = row * 2
    
    # Get value counts for pie chart
    value_counts = df[data_col].value_counts()
    # Create pie chart trace and add to subplot
    pie_chart = go.Pie(labels=value_counts.index, values=value_counts.to_numpy(), name=title, title=title)
    fig.add_trace(pie_chart, row=row+1, col=col+1)
 
    # get churn rates
    churn_counts = df.groupby([data_col, 'Churn'])['Churn'].count().unstack()
    # Create stacked bar charts
    t1 = go.Bar(name='Churn (yes)', x=churn_counts['Yes'].index, y=churn_counts['Yes'])
    t2 = go.Bar(name='Churn (no)', x=churn_counts['No'].index, y=churn_counts['No'], marker_color='indianred')
    fig.add_trace(t1, row=row+2, col=col+1)
    fig.add_trace(t2, row=row+2, col=col+1)


fig.update_layout(title="Distribution of Customer Services", barmode='stack', showlegend=False)
fig.show()
```

---

**Edit**: this issue is not fixed with decreasing the number of columns to two either. this is the chart on a large wide screen:
[image]

```py
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

# Read data
df = pd.read_csv("./WA_Fn-UseC_-Telco-Customer-Churn.csv")
df['SeniorCitizen'] = df['SeniorCitizen'].map({0: 'No', 1: 'Yes'})

# Define subplot titles and data columns
data_cols = ['PhoneService' ,'MultipleLines' ,'InternetService' ,'OnlineBackup' ,'DeviceProtection' ,'TechSupport' ,'StreamingTV' ,'StreamingMovies']
titles = ['Phone Service' ,'Multiple Lines' ,'Internet Service' ,'Online Backup' ,'Device Protection' ,'Tech Support' ,'Streaming TV' ,'Streaming Movies']

fig = go.FigureWidget(make_subplots(rows=8, cols=2, specs=[
                                                        [{'type':'domain'}, {'type':'domain'}],
                                                        [{'type':'xy'}, {'type':'xy'}],
                                                        [{'type':'domain'}, {'type':'domain'}],
                                                        [{'type':'xy'}, {'type':'xy'}],
                                                        [{'type':'domain'}, {'type':'domain'}],
                                                        [{'type':'xy'}, {'type':'xy'}],
                                                        [{'type':'domain'}, {'type':'domain'}],
                                                        [{'type':'xy'}, {'type':'xy'}]]))

row, col = 1, 0
for i, (title, data_col) in enumerate(zip(titles, data_cols)):
    row, col = divmod(i, 2)
    row = row * 2

    # Get value counts for pie chart
    value_counts = df[data_col].value_counts()
    # Create pie chart trace and add to subplot
    pie_chart = go.Pie(labels=value_counts.index, values=value_counts.to_numpy(), name=title, title=title)
    fig.add_trace(pie_chart, row=row+1, col=col+1)

    # get churn rates
    churn_counts = df.groupby([data_col, 'Churn'])['Churn'].count().unstack()
    # Create stacked bar charts
    t1 = go.Bar(name='Churn (yes)', x=churn_counts['Yes'].index, y=churn_counts['Yes'])
    t2 = go.Bar(name='Churn (no)', x=churn_counts['No'].index, y=churn_counts['No'], marker_color='indianred')
    fig.add_trace(t1, row=row+2, col=col+1)
    fig.add_trace(t2, row=row+2, col=col+1)


fig.update_layout(title="Distribution of Customer Services", barmode='stack', showlegend=False)
fig.show()
```

Comment: Adding vertical spacing and a graph size height of, say, 800 would improve the appearance. `fig = go.FigureWidget(make_subplots(...,vertical_spacing=0.05,);...fig.update_layout(height=800)`

Comment: Here's what the reference [example](https://plotly.com/python/subplots/#subplots-with-shared-xaxes) shows

Comment: @r-beginners `vertical_spacing` is relative. it can increase the size of one row while making the other too small to be useful.

Comment: The issue is not due to the spacing between subplots but to the resolution of the layout which by default fits your screen, which is too small to show all subplots properly. You can still set the layout' width & height and decrease the font size.

Comment: @EricLavault I've updated the question with new image. it's on a wide screen. I've even lowered the number of columns.

Comment: No, [_this_](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i4zgK.png) is the output on a widescreen with the default font size.

Answer (score 0):

The spacing between rows and columns can be adjusted with `vertical_spacing` and `horizontal_spacing` arguments respectively. Both can have a float value between 0 and `1/(size -1)`. It takes some tinkering to find the right value that suits you. To maximize the size of the charts within the figure you can update the `margin` argument within the `fig.update_layout` call. All four sides are referred to in a dictionary with the keys: `t`, `b`, `l` and `r`.

The code below is an alteration of yours that using all these arguments.

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

# Read data
df = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/joost/Downloads/WA_Fn-UseC_-Telco-Customer-Churn.csv")
df['SeniorCitizen'] = df['SeniorCitizen'].map({0: 'No', 1: 'Yes'})

# Define subplot titles and data columns
data_cols = ['PhoneService' ,'MultipleLines' ,'InternetService' ,'OnlineBackup' ,'DeviceProtection' ,'TechSupport' ,'StreamingTV' ,'StreamingMovies']
titles = ['Phone Service' ,'Multiple Lines' ,'Internet Service' ,'Online Backup' ,'Device Protection' ,'Tech Support' ,'Streaming TV' ,'Streaming Movies']

hor_space = 0.02
ver_space = 0.02

fig = go.FigureWidget(make_subplots(rows=4,
                                    cols=4,
                                    specs=[[{'type':'domain'}, {'type':'domain'}, {'type':'domain'}, {'type':'domain'}],
                                           [{'type':'xy'}, {'type':'xy'}, {'type':'xy'}, {'type':'xy'}],
                                           [{'type':'domain'}, {'type':'domain'}, {'type':'domain'}, {'type':'domain'}],
                                           [{'type':'xy'}, {'type':'xy'}, {'type':'xy'}, {'type':'xy'}]
                                           ],
                                    horizontal_spacing=hor_space, # in range 0 to 1/(cols-1)
                                    vertical_spacing=ver_space # in range 0 to 1/(rows-1)
                                    )
                      )

row, col = 1, 0
for i, (title, data_col) in enumerate(zip(titles, data_cols)):
    row, col = divmod(i, 4)
    row = row * 2
    
    # Get value counts for pie chart
    value_counts = df[data_col].value_counts()
    # Create pie chart trace and add to subplot
    pie_chart = go.Pie(labels=value_counts.index, values=value_counts.to_numpy(), name=title, title=title)
    fig.add_trace(pie_chart, row=row+1, col=col+1)
 
    # get churn rates
    churn_counts = df.groupby([data_col, 'Churn'])['Churn'].count().unstack()
    # Create stacked bar charts
    t1 = go.Bar(name='Churn (yes)', x=churn_counts['Yes'].index, y=churn_counts['Yes'])
    t2 = go.Bar(name='Churn (no)', x=churn_counts['No'].index, y=churn_counts['No'], marker_color='indianred')
    fig.add_trace(t1, row=row+2, col=col+1)
    fig.add_trace(t2, row=row+2, col=col+1)


fig.update_layout(title="Distribution of Customer Services",
                  barmode='stack',
                  showlegend=False,
                   margin={"l":25,
                           "r":25,
                           "t":25,
                           "b":25}
                  )
fig.show()
```

Some background provided by the plotly documentation:

- [Subplots](https://plotly.com/python/subplots/)
- [Sizing a graph](https://plotly.com/python/setting-graph-size/#adjusting-height-width--margins-with-graph-objects)